# Difference between h2o.download_mojo() and h2o.saveMojo()?

Tags: r, h2o

Both functions are available in version 3.18.0.4 and the only apparent difference is that h2o.saveMojo(force = T) allows you to overwrite an existing file with the same name. Why are there 2? Any relative (dis)advantage?
Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

H2O-3 is a client-server architecture.  The H2O Flow Web UI, the R session, the Python session are all clients.  The H2O java process is the server.

Often, the client and server are often running on the same host (for example, in the case where h2o is started with h2o.init()), and in those situations it can be hard to tell the difference between the client and the server.  But when you start a multi-node H2O job on Hadoop and connect to it explicitly from an R session using an IP address, the client and server separation becomes quite obvious to the user.

So with that as background:

- h2o.download_mojo() is the client pulling the mojo artifact, and storing it to the client filesystem
- h2o.saveMojo() is the server pushing the mojo artifact, either to the server filesystem or to a network filesystem (e.g. HDFS)

Comment: Thanks (Hvala) Tom :)